# java.awt.Robot keyPress event is keep on pressing

Tags: java, swing, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to create my own virtual keyboard in Java. I am using Robot's keyPress() event to trigger the KeyEvent to a text field. Key event is working but it keep on printing the key that I pressed.  Here is my code please check what I am doing wrong?

**Code for creating keyboard**

```
package virtualkeyboard;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Keyboard extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextField txtField;

    public Keyboard(JTextField txt) {

        this.txtField = txt;
        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
            createButton(Integer.toString(i));
        }

        pack();
    }

    private void createButton(String label) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(label);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        Font font = btn.getFont();
        float size = font.getSize() + 15.0f;
        btn.setFont(font.deriveFont(size));

        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                txtField.requestFocus();

                Robot robot;

                try {

                    robot = new Robot();

                    if(label.equals("0"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                    else if(label.equals("1"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    else if(label.equals("2"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    else if(label.equals("3"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                    else if(label.equals("4"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                    else if(label.equals("5"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                    else if(label.equals("6"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
                    else if(label.equals("7"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7);
                    else if(label.equals("8"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8);
                    else if(label.equals("9"))
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);

                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        add(btn);
    }
}
```

**Window with a textfield**

```
package virtualkeyboard;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class WindowOne extends JDialog {

    private JTextField txtField = new JTextField();

    private Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(txtField);

    public WindowOne(){

        setSize(new Dimension(250,30));

        txtField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(isEnabled()){
                    Point p = getLocationOnScreen();
                    p.y += 30;
                    keyboard.setLocation(p);
                    keyboard.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });

        add(txtField);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowOne().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Edits:**

I made the following changes in code and made the JTextfield focusable while press the button.

```
private void createButton(String label,JTextField txt) {

        JButton btn = new JButton(label);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        Font font = btn.getFont();
        float size = font.getSize() + 15.0f;
        btn.setFont(font.deriveFont(size));
        btn.setFocusable(false);

        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                txt.getParent().requestFocus();
                txt.requestFocus();

                robot.delay(100);

                if(label.equals("0"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                else if(label.equals("1"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                else if(label.equals("2"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                else if(label.equals("3"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                else if(label.equals("4"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                else if(label.equals("5"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                else if(label.equals("6"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
                else if(label.equals("7"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7);
                else if(label.equals("8"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8);
                else if(label.equals("9"))
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);

                requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        add(btn);
    }
```

If I press a button it's keep on printing the number in textfield. But event is fired only once.

Please check.

Comment: Fire a `keyReleased` event

Comment: I used keyReleased, now its fired event for once. Since my JTextField is in another JDialog keyPress is not fired in that textfiled

Comment: The text field would need to be in focus in order for it to receive key events. You may want to consider using `requrestFocusInWindow` instead of `requestFocus` and apply a delay between key events, if they are two fast, they may not be registered by the OS

Comment: keyboard JDialog is on top of all the JComponent's. How can I focus the JDialog which is below to keyboard component ( I mean how to focus textfield in JDialog, when I press the key in Keyboard JDialog) .

Comment: The question would be more about how you might make the `JDialog` and it's button unfocusable - but that would constrain your "virtual keyboard" to mouse input only

Comment: I made some changes in the mouse event in Keyboard class to focus the Jtextfiled dialog and back to the Keyboard panel. If i give KeyRelease() then event is not fired

Comment: I found the issue in repeating the button press.  we need to manually release the button after press this is worked for me  **robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);** **robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);**

Comment: @SharanDeSilva Please post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem,

For every keyPress event we need to trigger the appropriate keyRelease event then only it will stop the keyPress event, otherwise it will considred as a long press.

Changed this line

```
if(keyCode.equals("VK_0")){
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
}
```

to

```
if(keyCode.equals("VK_0")){
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);
}
```